# Scikit Multiflow Making Predictions

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

I am trying to make predictions by using created model but it returns `[array([0])]`
How can I see predicted results? The code is below.

```
from skmultiflow.trees import HoeffdingTreeClassifier
from skmultiflow.evaluation import EvaluatePrequential
from skmultiflow.data import FileStream

df = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/diabete/diabetes.csv', header=1)
stream = FileStream('/content/drive/My Drive/diabete/diabetes.csv')
ht = HoeffdingTreeClassifier()
evaluator = EvaluatePrequential(show_plot=False,
                                 pretrain_size=30,
                                 max_samples=20000, output_file="/content/drive/MyDrive/diabete/test.csv")

evaluator.evaluate(stream=stream, model=ht)
data=df.iloc[[2]]
x = evaluator.predict(data.iloc[:,:-1].values)
print(x)
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? it predicted that dataframe sample in index 2 has the class value of 0 meaning no diabetes.

Comment: does [array([0])] means that it predicts as zero?

Comment: the output of the predict function is an array of the prediction for each sample passed to the predict function. because you passed only one sample than it is an array of one prediction with value 0. so yeah it means it predicted as zero.